# How to know if jQuery is totally loaded?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm on android, and because I'm lazy I load jquery into a webview to manipulate the DOM.

I load my webview, and until jQuery is not defined, I have a loading screen to indicate the users he can't do anything.

```
if(info.equalsIgnoreCase("undefined"))
```

info is typeof(jQuery). He is undefined at the beginning, ~1sec later it's defined, but SURPRISE ! You don't have all the functions...

Explanations : Just after jQuery is defined, I tried a jQuery('body').remove()... I need to wait ~4sec later to do that. But if I just want to change the background of my body, it's working immediatly.

My question is : How to know when jQuery is TOTALLY loaded ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not jQuery that is not totally loaded, it's the DOM, use `$.ready` as others have mentioned

Comment: I am certain that the DOM is loaded because I wait before load jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to determine when the target selectors are available?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // load things
});
```

An alternative option would be to shim the body's onload event to trigger when the document body is finished loading, being sure to include jQuery in the body:

```
<body onload="fireItUp();">
  <script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
  window.fireItUp = function() {
    // load things
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

Ugly, but functional.

Comment: I tried already but it's like he nerver goes to that function... So I got an infinite loading screen.

Comment: I tried the $(document).ready system again and it's only enter into it when I add it after jQuery has finished loading so it's pointless.
The problem is the user choose when to "activate" jQuery, so I don't see how I can add jQuery that way, exept if I add it on every website he see, but yeah it's ugly :p. On other way maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

Once `jQuery` is available, you *do* have all the methods available.

You need to wait for the DOM to be ready.

```
$(function() {
    // DOM may be manipulated here.
});
```

Comment: Same thing that $(document).ready... Only enter into it when I add it AFTER jQuery is completely loaded